# Passing parameter in request handler is not showing correct results

Tags: android, requesthandler

New to android, it is a trivial issue but could not resolve in last 3 hours.

When I use the parameter called keyword, it is not showing correct results. otherwise it is working fine if I pass keyword value in the url. Not sure, how to pass the parameter in the url correctly so it retrieves correct result.

```
 RequestHandle requestHandle = client.get("http://koha-dev.cvpl.com.sg:9900/biblios?version=1.0&operation=searchRetrieve&query=" + keyword + "&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&recordSchema=dc", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
```

above is not showing correct results.

```
 RequestHandle requestHandle = client.get("http://koha-dev.cvpl.com.sg:9900/biblios?version=1.0&operation=searchRetrieve&query=knowledge&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&recordSchema=dc", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
```

is working correctly.

I tried to check the value of keyword:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "checkdetails " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Result is below:

checkdetails keyword=knowledge

Any suggestions are welcome. thanks in advance.

Comment: the value of keyword is 'keyword=knowledge' it should only 'knowledge'

Comment: I agree, but how to get the value as knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
                params.put("keyword", keyword);
```

to

```
                params.put("query", keyword);
```

which resolved the issue.